# Expected spy to have been called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following component with a method that displays a modal. If the user confirms by pressing 'OK', it would return an observable of true and if they cancel it returns an observable of false. However I am finding it difficult to apply a test case, to check if `this.onSwitchWindowClick()` is called with a response of `Observable.of(true)`.

```
public confirmSwitchWindow() {
    const modalConfig: ConfirmModalConfig = new ConfirmModalConfig(
        'modal title',
        'this is the modal message',
        [
            [this.translateService.instant('actions.confirm'), ConfirmButtonActions.YES],
            [this.translateService.instant('actions.cancel'), ConfirmButtonActions.CANCEL],
        ],
        ConfirmIcons.WARN,
    );

    this.confirmService.showConfirmModal(modalConfig, true).pipe(
        mergeMap((action: ConfirmButtonActions) => {
            if (action === ConfirmButtonActions.YES) {
                return Observable.of(true);
            } else {
                return Observable.of(false);
            }
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
            throw Observable.of(err);
        }),
    ).subscribe((value: boolean) => {
        if (value) {
            this.onSwitchWindowClick();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the test:

```
it('Should correctly confirm switch from planning window to production', async(() => {
    const spyShowConfirmModal = spyOn(confirmService, 'showConfirmModal').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true));
    const onSwitchWindowClick = spyOn(component, 'onSwitchWindowClick');
    component.confirmSwitchWindow();
    component.returnValue = true;
    expect(spyShowConfirmModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
    spyShowConfirmModal(null, true).subscribe((value) => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(onSwitchWindowClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
}));
```

The test fails: `"... FAILED: Expected spy onSwitchWindowClick to have been called."`

How does one fix this?

Comment: In the method you have provided I cannot see `onSwitchProductionClick`. Where is it actually?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: There seems to be some sort of discrepancy, the error message shows that you're spying on "onSwitchProductionClick" method, however, the above mentioned unit test is not spying on any such method. Are you sure, this unit test is throwing this error message.

Comment: Apologies its a typo, the answer has been updated

Comment: Put a `console.log('In subscribe: ', value);` in the `subscribe` block and then put a `console.log('in if block');` inside of the `if` statement. Make sure both log out when running the unit tests.